# Windows Server 2003 Graphics Issue

Tags: windows-server-2003

A few days ago I restarted my server, it may have installed a few updates, but after it started it looked really off. The drop shadows are not showing even though they're enabled, MS Office 07 and Frontpage 03 look like something from the 90s, and IE is displaying fonts and colors strange. The theming service is active and "Windows XP" theme is enabled. I'm trying to test in IE and everything is distorted. (Chrome and FF work fine, as does CS6) How do I fix this?

Some Pictures:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try a right-click on the desktop, and under the menu for "Arrange Icons By", un-check "Lock Web Items on Desktop".  Also make sure that you haven't disabled visual themes for any one program running, as this will affect the whole desktop.  This is found on the program shortcut's Properties, Compatibility tab.

Comment: Lock web items just changes the highlight to white. I have restarted multiple times and get the same result so it has nothing to do with a program running.